# How to fetch values from sqlite database and stored into array using objective c?

Tags: ios, iphone

```
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO employeedetails('employee_name','employee_mailid','employee_username','employee_password')VALUES('%@','%@','%@','%@')",self.textname.text,self.textmailid.text,self.textusername.text,self.textpassword.text];
    NSLog(@"%@The inserted values are",sql);
    char *err;
    if (sqlite3_exec(db,[sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err)!=SQLITE_OK) {

        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0,@"sdsadadsderererwrcould not update the tabel");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"nbbbbbbbbbbbbtable updated");
    }

}

-(void)selectfn
{
    const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM employeedetails";  // Your Tablename

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        [name removeAllObjects];

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            [name addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)]];
            NSLog(@"The array value is %@",name);
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

Already I have insert values into table...Now I want to fetch values from the table and want to store one nsarray and display into tableview....help me plz

Answer (score 0):

You can create Model class something like this

**Header file**

```
#import "Model.h"

@implementation Model 

@synthesize _firstValue ,_secondValue ;

@end
```

**Implementation file**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Model: NSObject
{
    NSString *_firstValue ;
    NSString *_secondValue ;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *_firstValue ;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *_secondValue ;

@end
```

Now fetching data using below lines...

```
  //Cretae a array to store values
    NSMutableArray *retArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        if ([self dbOpen]) // check db is open
        {
            const char *sqlStatement = [YOUR_QUERY UTF8String];
            sqlite3_stmt *statement;
            if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )
            {
                while( sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW )
                {

    // used model to fill the set of data
                    Model *obj = [[Model alloc] init];
                    obj._firstValue = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                    obj._secondValue = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];       
                    [retArr addObject:obj];
                    obj = nil;
                }
            }
            else {  NSLog( QRY_EXEC_ERROR, sqlite3_errmsg(database) );  } // excute if any error

            sqlite3_finalize(statement); // finalizing
            sqlite3_close(database); // clossing the DB
        }


Finally use retArr which holds your DB values.....
```

Comment: Hello sir, for this line " Model *obj = [[Model alloc] init];" I got an error...is their any library files to import to resolve the error

Comment: It's our custom model NSObject file.i updated code check once.You can use the same model when loading data into tableview

Comment: sir I have one more doubt here "obj._firstValue" what it means

Comment: obj is name of object of Model.To accessing properties(firstValue,secondValue) of it.you can add more properties like firstValue..etc in your Model class

Comment: if you dont want adding Model you can go with your way directly adding string into array.

Comment: sir I got hexadecimal values like....."<secondViewController: 0x7fbd9f719990>",
    "<secondViewController: 0x7fbd9f413e80>",
    "<secondViewController: 0x7fbd9f715390>",
    "<secondViewController: 0x7fbd9f717e00>"
  how can I get exact value sir